# Angular how to use translate i18n key as a function parameter in html

Tags: angular, internationalization, i18next, angular-translate

I am trying to pass i18n translate service key as a parameter function on html component.

I have tried the following but instead getting the text it's getting the key

I have assigned a variable with the title in component.ts

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(public translate: TranslateService,) {

}
public title= this.translate.instant('title-key');
```

and in component.html. I have this variable as a parameter function

```
<a class="nav-link" (click)="functionName(title)" > {{'title-key' | translate}}</a>
```

the title that should be sent is **tasks**
but instead it is sent the key -> **title-key**

```
functionName(tabSelected) {
  switch(tabSelected) {
      case this.title:
        this.tab = true;
      break;
      default:
   }
}

    <kendo-tabstrip #tabstrip [keepTabContent]="true">
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title] = "title" *ngIf="tab" [selected]="true">
            <ng-template kendoTabContent *loadOnDemand>
              <app-component></app-component>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
   <kendo-tabstrip>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your goal. What do you want to achieve? Please, describe the workflow. Do you just want to show some translation in the UI?

Comment: @Lynx242 yes I am trying to display tabs on the selected language. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always have trouble applying `click()` directly to an `<a>` tag. Try it this way:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)">
    <i class="nav-link" (click)="function(getTitle())">{{'title-key' | translate}}</i>
</a>
```

and you will indeed use the click function and not the href-event of the anchor.

**Your component**

```
public title: string;

constructor(private translate: TranslateService,) { 
}

getTitle(): string {
   return this.translate.instant('title-key');
}
```

Comment: thanks for advices. the function name just a sample I will edit the question now.
However this is not working..

Comment: Does it call your function? If so, what does console.log() say?

Comment: it prints 'title-key' instead of 'tasks'

Comment: Okay, now I know what your problem is! ngx-translate is not fast enough! You try to initialize the variable directly when the component starts with the translated key. This is to early for the service. try it differently. I'll update my example.